# A bag contains contains 20 blue marbles, 20 green marbles, and 20 red marbles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bag contains contains 20 blue marbles, 20 green marbles, and 20 red marbles.

Two marbles are drawn one after the other. **no replacement**

Using selection (combinations), find the probability of:

(a) drawing two marbles of the same colour

(b) drawing a blue and a green marble

(c) drawing a blue or a green marble

---

Would the sample space be P(60,2) or C(60,2)

Comment: You can use either, but best is to choose $C(60,2)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks for combinations, but permutation seems more intuitive to me in this question, as the order of the marbles being drawn has to be taken into account.

I would use $60P2$ as the sample space. By doing so, I have to treat all $60$ marbles as distinctive:

Blue: Marble $1$, Marble $2$, Marble $3$..., Marble $20$
Green: Marble $21$, Marble $22$, Marble $23$..., Marble $40$
Red: Marble $41$ to Marble $60$

(a) drawing two marbles of the same colour

$$\text {Probability} = \frac{20P2+20P2+20P2}{60P2}$$

(b) drawing a blue and a green marble

$$\text {Probability} = \frac{(20P1\times 20P1)+(20P1 \times 20P1)}{60P2}$$

(c) drawing a blue or a green marble

$$\text {Probability} = \frac{(20P1\times 40P1)+(20P1\times 40P1)}{60P2}$$

Look forward to an answer that uses combinations instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what is expected, but use for verification:

a) second is $\frac{19}{59}$ chance of being same color

b) first has $\frac{40}{60}$ chance of being successful, second has $\frac{20}{59}$ chance of being the other required color. Multiply the probability of first chance and second chance.

c) Anything except $2$ red, so the answer is $$1 - (\frac{20}{60}\times \frac{19}{59})=\frac{177-19}{177}=\frac{158}{177}$$